# How to embed images and text into one message?

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I have another issue programming my discord bot. The Issue stands when I try to make an embed that has Title, Description and Image in it. The issue is that the Title and Description are embedded and the image is sent as a different message.

Here is the code:

```
 [Command("spawn"), Summary("Spawn a monster")]
    public async Task Embed()
    {
        EmbedBuilder Embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        Embed.WithAuthor("‌‌Test Title");
        Embed.WithDescription("Test Description");
        Embed.WithThumbnailUrl($"{Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(@"Core\Data\1.png", "‌‌", false, null)}");
        Embed.WithColor(0, 255, 0);

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, Embed.Build());
    }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is you need to upload the png to somewhere and copy the URL of the png file. 
The reason for the BOT is sending two different message is that ...
This line:

```
Embed.WithThumbnailUrl($"{Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(@"Core\Data\1.png", "‌‌", false, null)}");
```

is equals with:

```
Embed.WithThumbnailUrl(null);
Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(@"Core\Data\1.png", "‌‌", false, null);
```

### Update

I found a solution

```
[Command("spawn"), Summary("Spawn a monster")]
public async Task Embed()
{
            RestUserMessage picture = await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(@"Resources\test.png");
            string imgurl = picture.Attachments.First().Url;
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, new EmbedBuilder { Title = "Test", Description = "Test", Color = new Color(0,255,0), ImageUrl = imgurl }.Build());
            await picture.DeleteAsync();
        }
```

First we send the picture and catch the message (`RestUserMessage picture = x`), after that we get the URL of the Attachment (`string imgurl = picture.Attachments.First().Url;`), after that we send the embed message with the picture URL (`ImageUrl = imgurl`) and finally we delete the only picture message (`await picture.DeleteAsync();`).

Comment: Sorry my english is not the best, but i hope you can understand it