# How do I add an image for a Discord bot in c#?

Tags: c#, image, discord

This is what I think that should work

I'm doing a bot for discord and I'm new to this, still trying to understand basics.
I would like to add an image with out any message attached, how do i do this?

```
public class Command : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("Image")]
    public async Task ReplyImage()
    {
        await ReplyAsync("image.url");
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930818/how-to-embed-images-and-text-into-one-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must embed the image
example :

```
public class Command : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    public async Task ReplyImage()
    {
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        embed.WithImageUrl("image.url");
        await ReplyAsync("", false, embed.Build());
    }
}
```

> **Tips :** `ReplyAsync` method is a part of the `ModuleBase` class from the Discord.Net library. You must add it by install `Discord.Net` from NuGet packages

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I just tried the code but the replyAsync thing don't work, as it says that it doesn't exists in the current document, do I need some libraries or sum?

Comment: @Simanonhonientedafareog , `ReplyAsync` method is a part of the `ModuleBase` class from the Discord.Net library. It seems that you're missing a reference to the Discord.Net . You must add it by install `Discord.Net`  from NuGet packages.